# How to build a query that includes # and @ in Twitter API v2?

Tags: twitter-api-v2

I'm not very good at interpreting how to build a `query=` with multiple operators. The below examples of attempts that are invalid for the [Twitter API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/api-reference/get-tweets-counts-recent#tab1) . Can someone show me how to make a proper query with multiple operators using the [Tweet Count API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/api-reference/get-tweets-counts-recent#tab1)?

Attempts (title: 'Invalid Request',
detail: 'One or more parameters to your request was invalid.',):

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?query=#animals OR @animals

https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?query=(#animals OR @animals)
```

Working (would like to combine these):

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?query=#animals

https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?query=@animals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It appears Twitter v2 API requires encoded `#` (`%23`), spaces (`%20`), and `@` (`%40`). The below query is valid:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?query=%23animals%20OR%20%40animals
```